# No se recogen los datos de Scanner ni se los muestra en array

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

Quisiera saber si alguien me podría decir por qué mi código java cargado desde netbeans no me recoge los datos de mi clase **Scanner** y tampoco los muestra en el **Arraylist**.

Lo que quiero realizar sería un programa de reserva de vacaciones en el que se calcularía un presupuesto, donde se cargan los datos globales de todos. Tengo dos clases principales *Hotel* y *Vuelo*, en la que cargo los datos de esas clases más los de la clase *Presupuesto* y una clase *Test* donde realizo la agregación de los datos de todos y que los muestre en un txt.

---

Presupuesto

---

```
public class Presupuesto {

    final double COMISION_GESTION = 8.25;

    static String DNI;
    static String nombre;
    static int numPasajeros;
    static String tipoDeServicio;
    static double precioBase;
    static int numDias;

    
    public Presupuesto(){
        
    }
    
    
    public Presupuesto(String DNI, String nombre, int numPasajeros, String tipoDeServicios,int numDias) {
        this.DNI = DNI;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numPasajeros = numPasajeros;
        this.tipoDeServicio = tipoDeServicios;
        this.numDias=numDias;
    }


    public String getTipoDeServicio() {
        return tipoDeServicio;
    }

    public void setTipoDeServicio(String tipoDeServicio) {
        this.tipoDeServicio = tipoDeServicio;
    }

    public void setDNI(String DNI) {
        this.DNI = DNI;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setNumPasajeros(int numPasajeros) {
        this.numPasajeros = numPasajeros;
    }

    public double getCOMISION_GESTION() {
        return COMISION_GESTION;
    }

    public String getDNI() {
        return DNI;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getNumPasajeros() {
        return numPasajeros;
    }
     public int getNumDias() {
        return numDias;
    }
    private void setPrecioBase(){
        this.precioBase=numPasajeros*COMISION_GESTION;
    }
}
```

---

EstanciaHotel

---

```
public class EstanciaHotel extends Presupuesto {

    final int hotelesCosta = 45;
    final int hotelesInterior = 35;
    final int CapitalesEu = 60;

    final int alojamiento = 5;
    final int mediaPension = 10;
    final int pensionCompleta = 15;

    static String ciudad;
    
    static String tipoLocalizacion;
    static String tipoDePension;
    static double precioFinal;

    public EstanciaHotel(String ciudad, int numDias, String tipoLocalizacion, String tipoDePension, double precioFinal, String DNI,
                         String nombre, int numPasajeros, String tipoDeServicios) {
        super(DNI, nombre, numPasajeros, tipoDeServicios,numDias);
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        
        this.tipoLocalizacion = tipoLocalizacion;
        this.tipoDePension = tipoDePension;
    }

    EstanciaHotel(){
        
    }

    public void calcularPrecio() {

        switch (this.tipoDePension) {
            case "Alojamiento":
                this.precioFinal = alojamiento + numDias * numPasajeros;
                break;
            case "Media Pension":
                this.precioFinal = mediaPension + numDias * numPasajeros;
                break;
            case "Pension Completa":
                this.precioFinal = pensionCompleta + numDias * numPasajeros;
                break;
            default:  //Pongo que por defecto sea el mas barato
                this.precioFinal = mediaPension;
                break;
        }
        this.precioFinal += super.COMISION_GESTION;
    }

    public int getHotelesCosta() {
        return hotelesCosta;
    }

    public int getHotelesInterior() {
        return hotelesInterior;
    }

    public int getCapitalesEu() {
        return CapitalesEu;
    }

    public int getAlojamiento() {
        return alojamiento;
    }

    public int getMediaPension() {
        return mediaPension;
    }

    public int getPensionCompleta() {
        return pensionCompleta;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

   

    public String getTipoLocalizacion() {
        return tipoLocalizacion;
    }

    public String getTipoDePension() {
        return tipoDePension;
    }

    public double getPrecioFinal() {
        return precioFinal;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getNombre() + "    " + this.getDNI() + "    " + this.getNumPasajeros() + "     " + this.getTipoDeServicio() + "    " + this.getPrecioFinal();
    }

}
```

---

Vuelo

---

```
public class Vuelo extends Presupuesto {

    final int tasaPeninsular = 100;
    final int tasaDentroDeEuropa = 150;
    final int tasaFueraDeEuropa = 200;

    static String ciudadDeSalida;
    static String ciudadDeDestino;
    static String tipoDeVuelo;
    static String idaOvuelta;
    static double precioFinal;

    public Vuelo(String ciudadDeSalida, String ciudadDeDestino, String tipoDeVuelo, String idaOvuelta, String DNI, 
                 String nombre, int numPasajeros, String tipoDeServicios,int numDias) {
        super(DNI, nombre, numPasajeros, tipoDeServicios, numDias);
        this.ciudadDeSalida = ciudadDeSalida;
        this.ciudadDeDestino = ciudadDeDestino;
        this.tipoDeVuelo = tipoDeVuelo;
        this.idaOvuelta = idaOvuelta;
    }

    Vuelo() {

    }

    public void calcularSueldo() {

        switch (this.tipoDeVuelo) {
            case "Peninsular":
                this.precioFinal = tasaPeninsular + COMISION_GESTION;
                break;
            case "Dentro de Europa":
                this.precioFinal = tasaDentroDeEuropa + COMISION_GESTION;
                break;
            case "Fuera de Europa":
                this.precioFinal = tasaFueraDeEuropa + COMISION_GESTION;
                break;
            default:  //Pongo que por defecto sea el mas barato
                this.precioFinal = tasaPeninsular;
                break;
        }
        this.precioFinal += super.COMISION_GESTION;
    }

    public int getTasaPeninsular() {
        return tasaPeninsular;
    }

    public int getTasaDentroDeEuropa() {
        return tasaDentroDeEuropa;
    }

    public int getTasaFueraDeEuropa() {
        return tasaFueraDeEuropa;
    }

    public String getCiudadDeSalida() {
        return ciudadDeSalida;
    }

    public String getCiudadDeDestino() {
        return ciudadDeDestino;
    }

    public String getTipoDeVuelo() {
        return tipoDeVuelo;
    }

    public String getIdaOvuelta() {
        return idaOvuelta;
    }

    public double getPrecioFinal() {
        return precioFinal;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getNombre() + "    " + this.getDNI() + "    " + this.getNumPasajeros() + "     " + this.getTipoDeServicio() + "    " + this.getPrecioFinal();
    }
}
```

---

### Test

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Test extends Presupuesto{

    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     static boolean vueloValido = false;
     static boolean tipoValido = false;
     static String hotel_vuelo = "";
     public  Test(String DNI, String nombre, int numPasajeros, String tipoDeServicios,boolean vueloValido, boolean tipoValido,String hotel_vuelo
     ,int numDias){
          super(DNI, nombre, numPasajeros, tipoDeServicios,numDias);
          this.vueloValido=vueloValido;
          this.tipoValido=tipoValido;
          this.hotel_vuelo=hotel_vuelo;
     }
   
    public static boolean contratarVacaciones() {
        
        
        while (!vueloValido) {
            System.out.println("¿Que tipo de servicio se le ofrece?(Vuelo o Hotel)");
            hotel_vuelo = teclado.next();
            if (!hotel_vuelo.equalsIgnoreCase("vuelo") && !hotel_vuelo.equalsIgnoreCase("hotel")) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca un servicio valido.");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
            } else {
                vueloValido = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Introduzca su DNI: ");
        DNI = teclado.next();
        System.out.print("Introduzca cuantos pasajeros sereis: ");
        numPasajeros = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca cuantos dias va a estar: ");
        numDias = teclado.nextInt();

        while (!tipoValido) {
            if (hotel_vuelo.equalsIgnoreCase("hotel")) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca que tipo de pension: (Solo Alojamiento, Media Pension, Pension Completa)");
                String tipoDePension = teclado.nextLine();
                if ((!tipoDePension.equals("Solo Alojamiento") && !tipoDePension.equals("Media Pension")) && !tipoDePension.equals("Pension Completa")) {
                    System.out.println("No ha introducido una opcion valida.");
                    System.out.println("---------------------");
                } else {
                    tipoValido = true;
                    System.out.println("La operacion fue un exito");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Introduzca que tipo de vuelo desea (Dentro de la Peninsula, Europa, Fuera de Europa)");
                String tipoDeVuelo = teclado.nextLine();
                if (!tipoDeVuelo.equals("Dentro de la Peninsula") && !tipoDeVuelo.equals("Europa") && !tipoDeVuelo.equals("Fuera de Europa")) {
                    System.out.println("No ha introducido un tipo valido.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                } else {
                    tipoValido = true;
                    System.out.println("La operacion fue un exito");
                }
            }
        }
       //se que tengo que hacer returns pero me daban fallos
        return vueloValido;
        
    }

    public static void ordenarPorNombres(Presupuesto[] array) {
        Presupuesto aux;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j + 1].getNombre().compareTo(array[j].getNombre()) < 0) {
                    aux = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Presupuesto[] presupuestos = new Presupuesto[6];
        presupuestos[0] = new EstanciaHotel();
        presupuestos[1] = new EstanciaHotel();
        presupuestos[2] = new EstanciaHotel();
        presupuestos[3] = new Vuelo();
        presupuestos[4] = new Vuelo();
        presupuestos[5] = new Vuelo();
        int hoteles = 0, vuelos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
           if (presupuestos[i] instanceof EstanciaHotel) {
                hoteles++;
            } else if (presupuestos[i] instanceof Vuelo) {
                vuelos++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Vuelos: " + vuelos + "\nHoteles: " + hoteles);
        String texto = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < presupuestos.length; i++) {
           texto += presupuestos[i].toString();
            texto += "\n";
        }
        try {
            File archivo = new File("agenciaViajes.txt");
            FileWriter lapiz = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
            lapiz.write(texto);
            lapiz.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al escribir.");
        }
        try{
            FileReader lector = new FileReader("agenciaViajes.dat");
            BufferedReader contenido = new BufferedReader(lector);
            String textoLeido;
            while((textoLeido=contenido.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(textoLeido);
            }
            contenido.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error al leer");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: El scaner y carga del  array está en el método Contratar vacaciones pero en 'main'  no veo en que parte lo invocas..

Comment: esta justo al comienzo del main

Comment: Doy fe de que no está

Comment: Nos referimos a que no se invoca dentro del método main. Al principio de la clase Test sí está pero nadie lo llama.

Comment: Aparte que la ejecución de ese método no tendría ningún efecto en los elementos almacenados en el array de presupuestos

Comment: perdon ese es el codigo de la clase test del viejo en el nuevo lo que hay de distinto es que tiene puesto         contratarVacaciones(); en el main en antes del array

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta con esa modificación pero ya te digo que no tendrá ningún efecto final en el array de presupuestos

Comment: Otra cosilla que tengas en cuenta, estás escribiendo y luego leyendo de ficheros con nombre distinto. Y te recomendaría poner una ruta absoluta, sino te va a crear el fichero donde se esté ejecutando la máquina virtual de java. Si estás ejecutando en Windows algo como "C:\\viajesStack\\agenciaViajes.txt"

Comment: La verdad, no puedo encontrar quien o donde se llama a  contratarVacaciones(). ¿Ese no será tu problema que te has olvidado del llamado a contratarVacaciones() es quien captura los datos.? Cómo no hay una llamada a este , entonces, no se recogen los datos del scanne